# How to Add two textview next to each other in alert dialog Android

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.personal_info);
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layout.setPadding(20,20,20,0);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
           // layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
              layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    
     // Set up the input

        final TextView scan_text = new TextView(context);
        final TextView customer_name_text = new TextView(context);
        final TextView customer_wasa_text = new TextView(context);
        customer_wasa_text.setPaddingRelative(0,5,0,0);
        final TextView customer_mob_text = new TextView(context);
        customer_mob_text.setPaddingRelative(0,5,0,0);
        final TextView customer_email_text = new TextView(context);
        customer_email_text.setPaddingRelative(0,5,0,0);
        final TextView plot_type=new TextView(context);
        plot_type.setPaddingRelative(0,5,0,0);
        final TextView customer_address_text = new TextView(context);
        customer_address_text.setPaddingRelative(0,5,0,0);
        final TextView customer_new_address_text = new TextView(context);
        customer_new_address_text.setPaddingRelative(0,5,0,0);
        final EditText customer_name_input = new EditText(context);
        //customer_wasa_text.setPaddingRelative(0,2,0,0);
        /*final EditText customer_wasa_input = new EditText(context);*/
        //customer_wasa_input.setPaddingRelative(0,0,0,0);
        final EditText customer_mob_input = new EditText(context);
        final EditText customer_email_input = new EditText(context);
        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);

        `ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray)`;

        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setSelection(2);

        final EditText customer_address_input = new EditText(context);


/* final EditText customer_new_address_input = new EditText(context);*/
    final ImageView imageview=new ImageView(context);
    customer_name_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
    customer_name_input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30)});
    customer_wasa_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
    customer_mob_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
    customer_email_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
    customer_address_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
    customer_address_input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100)});
            /*customer_address_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
            customer_address_input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(50)});*/
            customer_new_address_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
            customer_new_address_input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100)});
        scan_text.setText("Scan QR/Barcode");
        scan_text.setTextSize(15);
        scan_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008080"));
        scan_text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        customer_name_text.setText(R.string.enter_customer_name);
        //customer_name_text.setText(R.string.enter_customer_name);
        customer_wasa_text.setText(idbuilder);
        customer_mob_text.setText(R.string.enter_mobile_no);
        customer_email_text.setText(R.string.enter_email_address);
        plot_type.setText(plotbuilder);
        customer_address_text.setText(R.string.enter_address);
        customer_new_address_text.setText("Enter new Address");
```

[image: That is what I have achieved]

I am stuck at a point that how to add two text views next to each other in alert dialog  Android.I want to add a textview or button at the point red circle I made and I do not know how to achieve it.

I have posted the code to get you better understanding that what I have done and what I have to achieve ,

I want to achieve my goal with out changing my parent layout orientation and it is Vertical

Comment: did you try the dialog box?

Comment: no, I have already designed a alert dialog and want to make changes in it , I want onlyto show 2 textviews next to each other , if you know  how to do it in dialog box, you can help me thank you

Comment: Please add the details of your actual issue to your question

Comment: Sir my actual problem is that I want to add a text view or a button next to the edit text in alert dialog

Comment: Can you plz add some code

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom layout xml for your dialog. for example: [Alert dialog with Custom layout](https://android.pcsalt.com/create-alertdialog-with-custom-layout-using-xml-layout/)

In your layout xml you can set your view as per your need.

Comment: sir is there any other way? with out xml layout I mean can I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Two textviews next to each other-

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Through Code-

1.Create a Horizontal linear layout programmatically-

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);

layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

2.Create Textviews and add it to linearlayout

```
TextView tv1= new TextView (context);
 ....
TextView tv2= new TextView (context);
...
layout.addView(tv1);
layout.addView(tv2);
```

Comment: sir not by xml I want to add programmatically

Comment: Sir I am posting my code to get better understand , thank you

Comment: @AwaisKhan code where you adding those views to dialog is not posted by you but just like you are adding those textviews to your alert dialog,add this horizontal linear layout(which has two textviews side by side) to your alert dialog